# A sort-of reversed cascaded delete 1-many

Tags: php, mysql

I've had a search and didn't find quite what I was looking for so apologies if this has already been asked...

I'm using a combo of PHP and MYSQL.

I have a table 'member' with a foreign key to an 'address' table.

The member table:

```
CREATE TABLE __JEH_MEMBER (" .
    "id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, " .
    "title VARCHAR(". self::TITLE_MAX_STRLEN ."), " .
    "forename VARCHAR(". self::NAME_MAX_STRLEN .") NOT NULL, " .
    "surname VARCHAR(". self::NAME_MAX_STRLEN .") NOT NULL, " .
    "addr_id INT NOT NULL, " .
    "bday DATE, " .
    "FOREIGN KEY(addr_id) REFERENCES __JEH_ADDRESS(id)" .
    // Note: No cascade spec here deliberately for now..
") ENGINE=InnoDB;";
```

The address table:

```
"CREATE TABLE __JEH_ADDRESS(" .
    "id       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, " .
    "street1  VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, " .
    "street2  VARCHAR(120), " .
    "street3  VARCHAR(120), " .
    "street4  VARCHAR(120), " .
    "city     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " .
    "state    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " .
    "country  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " .
    "postcode VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL" .       
") ENGINE=InnoDB;";
```

If I delete a user, I want to delete the address only if no other user also lives at that address.

So, my question is, is there some clever reverse of a cascaded delete where the database would know how to do this or do I need to stick with my existing method of locking both tables, checking the condition, and then only deleting the address if no one else references it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a multi table delete on a left join, like this:

```
DELETE m, a
FROM __JEH_MEMBER m
LEFT JOIN __JEH_ADDRESS a ON a.id = m.addr_id
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
  (SELECT addr_id FROM __JEH_MEMBER) AS x
  WHERE addr_id = m.addr_id
) = 1
WHERE m.id = ???
```

Note that the `(SELECT addr_id FROM __JEH_MEMBER) AS x` creates a temporary table which may have performance implications, so I'm not sure if this is an ideal solution. But it does work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete user. Search user table for other users with that address if not found delete address.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I've already listed that as my existing solution :) I wanted to know if there is a standard SQL interface that does this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it manually, but that could be in a trigger of type after-delete. Maybe that makes things faster or a bit more generic, since you could try writing a stored procedure with the dependencies as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but an even simpler answer is:

1. Set up your foreign key constraints as you have them
2. Find the addr_id that you want to maybe delete: `select addr_id into @addr_id from __JEH_MEMBER where ...`
3. Remove the current reference to that address: `delete from __JEH_MEMBER where ...`
4. Try and remove the address: `delete from __JEH_ADDRESS where id = @addr_id`

Note that due to the PRIMARY KEY constraints, step 4 will fail if there are any references to it still outstanding, but succeed if you just removed the last reference.